# android music player to sort/select by album

Tags: android, music, media-player

My Nokia phone music player is able to select music by album metadata. Android music players I tried when asked to select by albums brake albums further by authors resulting in several albums of same name for my music collection.

I want to listen to whole albums regardless of authors. Is there any such music player for Android?

Comment: How's your music organized? If you e.g. use a folder structure supporting that, there are apps [playing by folder](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay). Otherwise you might take a look at [the general suspects](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_jukeboxen) while waiting for recommendations. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking out [Poweramp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer&hl=en). It offers a free trial but I think its worth the price. It allows you to set your own custom sorting based off your music metadata or you can use a `folder` option that will just let you browse your music like a file browser.

[image: Poweramp folders]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Musixmatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.musixmatch.android.lyrify&hl=en) you can synce lyrics, album covers, search musics by listening to music,... . It's free.